# binary trees in c++, pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, binary-search-tree

I've been implementing binary trees, read a lot of code and articles, but didn't find answer to my problem. I have a class 'btree', structure 'node', and many methods. I want to write method for DSW algorythm. 
@edit - (Day-Stout-Warren Algorythm - the problem is to make a tree have only right branch, like a list of elements)

```
struct node{
    int key_value;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
```

I have rotation methods like this:

```
node *btree::ll_rotation(node *leaf){
    node *temp;
    temp = leaf->right;
    leaf->right = temp->left;
    temp->left = leaf;
    return temp;
}
node *btree::rr_rotation(node *leaf){
    node *temp;
    temp=leaf->left;
    leaf->left = temp->right;
    temp->right = leaf;
    return temp;
}
```

and now the problem:
when I use these methods and 'root' (root is declared in class), then it works, for example:

```
void btree::dsw1(){ 
    root=dsw1(root);
}
node *btree::dsw1(node *leaf){
    while (leaf->left) {leaf=rr_rotation(leaf);}
    return leaf;
}
```

this works, until I change the node, for ex. 'leaf=leaf->right'
I want to make all the tree one line, so I would have to code:

```
node *btree::dsw1(node *leaf){
    while(leaf!=NULL){
        if (leaf->left) {leaf=rr_rotation(leaf);}
        else if (leaf->right) leaf = leaf->right;
        else break;
    }
    return leaf;
}
```

This function doesn't work. the only way I can finish creating the line is writing

```
dsw1(root);
dsw1(root->right);
dsw1(root->right->right);
...
dsw1(root->right....);
```

Could you please tell me why it doesn't work if I create any new pointer and try to go deeper in the tree? Thank you for help.

This code doesn't work

```
node *btree::dsw1(node *leaf){
    node *temp;
    temp=leaf;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if (temp->left) {temp=rr_rotation(temp);}
        else if (temp->right) temp = temp->right;
        else break;
    }
    while (parent(temp)) {temp=parent(temp);}
    return temp;
}
```

And without the line

```
while (parent(temp)) {temp=parent(temp);}
```

doesn't work too

@up2

```
void btree::dsw1(){
    node *temp;
    temp=root->left->right;
    temp=rr_rotation(temp);
    root->left->right=temp;
}
```

This code works, but I don't how to understand it and how to use the knowledge to fix my code, which is meant to work on every tree, so i cannot use ->..->..->

@UP3

FINALLY, recursion wins - here is the code that I hope won't make any more problems. Thank you for your suggestions and help, I think I have finished this part. Thank you a million!
This function converts a tree into one-branch-tree (list of elements):

```
node *btree::dsw1(node *leaf){
    while(leaf->left) {leaf=rr_rotation(leaf);}
    if (leaf->right) leaf->right=dsw1(leaf->right);
    return leaf;
}
```

Bye!

Comment: I'm not up to date on my acronyms, please edit your post with the clarification of "DSW".

Comment: sorry for that and thank You for your suggestion - I edited the question.

Comment: Run it through a debugger to find out.

Comment: Or draw it out on paper, and visually track what `rr_rotation` is doing.  Don't forget to include the parent node that points to the parameter `leaf`.

Comment: I've been checking the rotations and they work as long as I give all the path from the root, for ex:  root->right->left->right = rr_rotation(root->right->left->right) works, but when I do like in the code above, it doesn't

Comment: You're assigning to function parameters. This has as much effect on the outside world as `void f(int x) { x = 0; }` has. There's nothing special about pointers.

Comment: @molbdnilo has it. Try making that node you pass in a pointer to a pointer [edit: or reference to a pointer] and operate on it. Your results might change.

Comment: I tried adding : node *temp; temp=leaf; and than working on 'temp', but It didn't change anything :/ I also did going back up to the root and than returning but there is also no change

Comment: Thank you all for help, I think I finished, If you want to know how I coded, look to the edited post, bye